# Save Current user while Offline

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I am having trouble updating an array saved in the current user while offline. While online it works perfectly, but when I am offline it gives me an error saying you cant do this after previous operation.

I tried to use pinning and saveEventually but neither worked.
Thanks for any help

```
 if(isConnected()) {
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().removeAll("Courses", courses);
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().addAllUnique("Courses", courses);
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
        }else{
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().pinInBackground();
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().removeAll("Courses", courses);
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().pinInBackground();
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().addAllUnique("Courses", courses);
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().pinInBackground();
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveEventually();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may arise from the following two lines:

```
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().pinInBackground();
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveEventually();
```

In the documentation, it says that `.saveEventually()` pins the object in the background until the network is available. So I think that you can just omit the

```
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().pinInBackground();
```

line as the `saveEventually()` method will pin it. Hope this helps.